Bootstrap_package custom Template
I use TYPO3 version 12 in the latest version for the TYPO3 Bootstrap package version 14.
https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package
I now want to outsource templates, but it doesn't work. When I make changes to my modified templates, I always get the output from the Bootstrap extension:
Here is my Typoscript:
plugin.tx_bootstrappackage {
  view {
    layoutRootPaths {
      10 = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/bootstrap_package/Layouts/
    }
    partialRootPaths {
      10 = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/bootstrap_package/Partials/
    }
    templateRootPaths {
      10 = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/bootstrap_package/Templates/
    }
  }
}

Change made to sitepackage/Resources/Private/bootstrap_package/Templates/ContentElements/Header.html. But these are not displayed to me.
Why?

Remove the Typoscript setup you made and instead set this to the Typoscript constants of your sitepackage extension:
plugin.tx_bootstrappackage {
    view {
        templateRootPath = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/bootstrap_package/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/bootstrap_package/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/bootstrap_package/Layouts/
    }
}

And check the template module in the backend, to make sure, that your Typoscript constants are loaded.

If you are not willing to provide all templates, partials, layouts you should make sure to include also the paths to the original files from the bootstrap package.
Therefore your paths should occur with a higher number additional to the original paths.

That could be done with adding your paths in the appropriate constants (use constant editor)
or by analyzing the given TypoScript setup and choose higher numbers.

Then FLUID will use all files from the path with the highest number the file exists in.
So you only have to copy and modify those files you want to modify.
